# Oven outlet not connected to breaker panel?

Tags: electrical

Replacing a gas range with an electric range.  There is an electric range outlet already installed, but when we plug the range in, there is no power.  We removed the outlet cover, and can see that there are wires attached.  But, when looking at the circuit breaker panel, we don't see anything that would be for the stove.  Any ideas?  Are we missing something?  Is it possible the builder (home built in 2005 in Ontario, Canada) added the outlet but then left it unconnected to power? [image][image][image]

Comment: since they used a gas range there was no reason to complete the circuit. But you have the plug and the wires,

Comment: @Ruskes well, wires at least at the *outlet.*  The panel pic is so tiny we can't tell if the wires go to the panel too. :)

Comment: Could you please [edit] in a larger picture of the panel, and include the space above and below it since it appears to be surface-mounted and that would allow looking at the cables going into it? If you are comfortable taking the cover off, that would be even more helpful, but at a minimum a bigger picture would show things that can't be seen here.

Comment: Aside - photo1 shows red/white/black wires going to the socket, but we can't see if the earth wire is connected.  Is the bare copper wire connected to the socket ?

Comment: Try giving the three wires in the wall a gentle tug - see if they only go in the wall a short distance and are just stubs  ?   If fixed, try and see if the wires go up or down.  Do you have access to your ceiling space or underfloor space respectively ?

Comment: To see if the wires are connected at all, you can measure continuity/resistance between the neutral white wire and the bare ground wire. If it shows close to 0 ohms, the cable connects to at least something. If it shows more than 1000 ohms, the cable is cut or disconnected somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

Anything is possible here. The likely odds are either the wires are there and a breaker to go with them is not, or there's a switched-off breaker in some sub-panel you haven't checked. *I'd completely expect the electric stove outlet breaker (if present) to be switched off with a gas stove installed.*

*The tiny picture makes it impossible to examine the possibilities at the breaker panel very well from this side of a computer screen.*

Answer (score 5):

It is very possible that the wires were either run to the inside of the panel but never connected to anything, or they were connected to a breaker and a new circuit run to that breaker (EV charging, workshop equipment, secondary HVAC, etc.) and the wires abandoned.

If you feel comfortable doing so, remove the front cover of the breaker panel. Don't touch any wires. Just *look* for a 3-wire cable (red/black/white/bare ground) that is not connected, hopefully with wire nuts on the ends of the wires to keep things safe. You may find black and red capped off but white (neutral) and/or the ground wire still connected, depending on who did the work.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible the breaker is tripped to the off/disconnected position but still looks like it is on/connected. You can flip all 13 of the double width breakers off (wait a few seconds) then back on. In doing this you can skip any breakers that are labeled for things that you know are working. Then try the oven outlet again.

If that doesn't work you'll have to open the box and LOOK around. It would be helpful if one of the wires leading in to the box is labelled something like stove/oven/range.